# Don't delete answers silently: instead, inform the author

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

I've just noticed that one of my answers got [deleted](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/28574/1832) by a mod. I was not informed of the deletion. Please don't delete answer silently but instead, inform the author.

[image]

Comment: [This hasn't changed in 9 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209694/) and asking yet another duplicate, on a site that isn't Meta no less, will not help.

Comment: @Nij I'm asking for the mods here to leave a comment when deleting an answer, not changing the SE system

Comment: That is not normal practise, and I see no reason for a routine deletion to need further commentary.

Comment: @Nij that is not a routine deletion.

Comment: Low quality answer; issue was mentioned in comment; issue not resolved; answer deleted. Very definitely and entirely routine.

Comment: @Nij  the answer addressed the question and had a source. I replied to the comment accordingly

Comment: I somewhat agree with the OP. Getting stuff deleted is always a pain in the back. And when something gets deleted that at least seems to be correct, a clarification definitely helps. Not everyone is used to the extremely strict moderation on this site.

Comment: And I don't agree with the close reason of this post. A serious question about something that happened on the main site can't seriously be opinion based? It did happen, so it's based on facts.

Comment: I don't mind it being opened, the real reason I (and Nij) closed it was that it's effectively a duplicate of a [meta.se] post, but that's not possible (to close-as-duplicate on another site) so I was just using that as the easiest way to get past that technical restriction.

Comment: As for strict moderation, I very much hope you don't feel that we have strict moderation here - this is one of the looser sites I am on moderation wise, at least as far as I see it.  We do have to be reasonably aggressive about removing clearly inappropriate content on a site that gets very little content in the first place, though, or else it leads to more inappropriate content.

Comment: @Joe I often have the feeling that you guys are very strict. Not aggressive, but strict. As a long-time member I don't mind, unless my comments magically disappear for little to no reason. I know what I have to expect when coming here. New users don't feel welcome, though. This is bad for a small SE site, because the community won't grow when newbies get scared away. Bad posts get closed/deleted too often instead of editing them into something better. But that's just my opionen. It's not necessarily a fact, only because I see it this way.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted this, as it did not meet the answer guidelines.  While it technically is "an answer", it was simply a repost of an answer from a reddit user to the identical question on reddit (asked by the same poster).  This is not an answer at the quality level that we expect on this site, and I commented to that effect.  When the answer was not updated to be a relevant answer, I deleted it.

In this case, I did you the courtesy of commenting prior to deletion to give you a chance to improve the answer.  This is not a typical thing to do; with answers from drive-by posters and similar, we do not necessarily comment prior to deleting as it has not been useful in the past.  This time, I did, as you're a poster who's been around the block and should know how the system works, hoping you would improve the answer.

When you replied, suggesting that you were not going to update the answer, I then deleted it, as leaving answers of lower quality encourages other similar answers.  You don't get a notification when that occurs, and will not. In the future, please try to address quality issues when they are brought to your attention.